# How to change the content of wordpress lostpassword mail?

Tags: php, wordpress

how to edit the content of wordpress lostpassword mail by myself. please tell me which file I should change or how to do this? Thank you very much.
Here is the content now:

有人申请了修改密码：
站点：www.***.com
用户名：***

点击http:www.***.com/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=5MaB8OJzKVY7YP6kGmW9&login=***

Comment: you used any plugin for register ya default wordpress functionality to lost password ? if use any plugin then specify plugin name please

Comment: You might wanna look at this link:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103299/customizing-lost-password-email

Comment: @kuldipMakadiya No I don't use these plugin.I think this mail is original, just using Chinese.